# Counting specific Tic-Tac-Toe games

Tags: python, counting, tic-tac-toe

There are 9!=362880 possible boards in a game of Tic-Tac-Toe ignoring a player winning early. Therefore of these 362880 boards, there should be 8*3!*6! = 34560 games that have the starting player have three stones in a line by the 5th move. Unfortunately though, belows code counts only 21600 boards.

Does someone see the error?

```
all_boards = list()
winning_boards = [[1, 2, 3],
                  [4, 5, 6],
                  [7, 8, 9],
                  [1, 4, 7],
                  [2, 5, 8],
                  [3, 6, 9],
                  [1, 5, 9],
                  [3, 5, 7]]


def build_all_boards(cur, moves_left):
    if moves_left == 0:
        all_boards.append(cur)
        return
    for i in range(1, 10):
        if i in cur:
            continue
        else:
            temp = cur.copy()
            temp.append(i)
            build_all_boards(temp, moves_left - 1)


def check_win(moves):
    for winning_board in winning_boards:
        s1 = set(moves)
        s2 = set(winning_board)
        if s1 == s2:
            return True
    return False


def count(c):
    build_all_boards([], c)
    won_boards = list()
    for board in all_boards:
        temp = board[::2][:3]
        if check_win(temp):
            won_boards.append(temp)
    print(len(won_boards))


count(9)
```

EDIT: Fixed code.

Comment: Can you explain why there should be `8*3!*6! = 34560` boards? As it turns out `5*3!*6!` is `21600`.

Comment: Agree w/ comment above.  Additionally, you appear to be counting "boards" as unique based on order of play to get 9!.  Your approach to counting will bite you because you are using set comparison, which does not account for order.  So a play of [1, 2, 3] would match [2, 1, 3] which would be from different "boards" in your accounting.

Comment: How come it's `9!`? The upper bound is `3**9 = 19683`.

Comment: @user10987432, 8 winning lines, 3! permutations coming from 3 moves and then 6! arbitrary possible moves left, that don't matter.
5! * 3!  * 6! is indeed a helpful observation.

Comment: @bereal, I don't see how you get 3**9 - different game (?), I simply count possible arrangments of the numbers from 1 to 9.

Comment: Do you count games or boards? It's not the same. Each cell can be X, O or empty, that gives 3**9 possible boards maximun (not all of them make sense).

Comment: @bereal, I am counting boards. 3**9 is simply the number states, ignoring order of moves, etc. 
In my case however I do  count moves and players setting alternatively and player one starting.

Comment: @JeffH, regarding the biting: I don't think you know, what you are talking about. Your comment does not seem to be truely relevant to the problem.

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what you are going after here with the now revised code.  Disregard if not helpful.  Did you get the answer you're looking for?  I'm not sure of your count of winning boards after 5 moves...specifically why you are multiplying by 6!  At the end of the 5th round, there are only 5 marks on the board total.

Comment: There 8 winning rows for the 1th player, 3! ways to respect the order of moves and the remaining 6 fields of the game board can be filled in any order, thus 6!. Then you get all possible boards that would end after the 5th move.

Comment: I agree with that only under the assumption that you let the game go beyond the 5th move.  At the conclusion of the 5th move, under the assumption that order of play matters, I think you have 8 * 3! * permute(6, 2).  Anyhow, sounds like you have it solved.